# How to disable image from saving into internal memory while downloading from an url

Tags: android, bitmapimage, imagedownload

I am using the following code to download an image from an url, then saving to sqlite and then view in imageview in an activity.

```
new LoadProfileImage().execute(jsonObject.getString("image"), id, title, promoexpdate, String.valueOf(i),flag,promostartDate);
```

The above code is used to call the function to do the above work.

```
private class LoadProfileImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    ImageView bmImage;
    String x,y,z,a,w,s;

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... uri) {
        String url = uri[0];
        Log.d("ImageURL",url);
        x = uri[1];
        y = uri[2];
        z = uri[3];
        a = uri[4];
        w = uri[5];
        s = uri[6];
        Log.d("LogValue",url+x+y+z+a+w+s);
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ErroronImageParsing", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if (result != null) {
            int width = result.getWidth();
            int height = result.getHeight();
            Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, width / 2, height / 2, true);
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            newBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            buffer = out.toByteArray();
            if (result!= newBitmap){
                result.recycle();
            }
            Log.d("ImageUploaded", "Success");
        }
            try {
                dbManager.open();
                Cursor cursor  = dbManager.fetch_PromsID(x);

                if (cursor.getCount() > 0){

                    String fla = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PRO_FLAG));
                    String pri_ID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.PRO_ID));

                    if (!w.equals(fla)) {
                        dbManager.update_Promotions(pri_ID,y,z, buffer,w,s);
                    }
                }else {
                    dbManager.insertPromotions(x,y,z,buffer,w,s);
                }


            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                SqliteData();
                panel.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            dbManager.close();
    }


}
```

Here, when the code below is executed, image from the url is saved into internal storage. I wish to disable the auto saving while maintaining my intention. Thanks in advance...

```
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, width / 2, height / 2, true);
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
newBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
buffer = out.toByteArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use third library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or [Glid](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) 
that offer

1. loading without caching
2. loading with memory or storage caching

you can do it with single line of code

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageUrl)
            .error(R.drawable.error)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE, MemoryPolicy.NO_STORE)
            .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Here am storing byte[] data of the image into sqlite so that when there is no network connectivity I can use the byte[] data. Since I am using byte[], I have to use the below code: 

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            newBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
            buffer = out.toByteArray();

Whenever I use this code, It automatically saves an image in the gallery. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: ok, i got it. 
try this 
`MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
byte[] bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
return bitmapData; `

Comment: Isn't MemoryStream based on Xamarin? Any android code to work out the above code? If am wrong, can you point it out on how to use your code?